# convert moment js format to defaultformat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to convert this date, Dec, 9th 2019, 05:23 AM, of which i got using format='MMM Do YYYY, hh:mm A' to the default format. But I keep getting 'Date '. I am using moment js, I don't know if this is actually possible, but I would like to know

below is my sample code

```
        const data = moment('Dec, 9th 2019, 05:23 AM', moment.defaultFormat).toDate();
        console.log(data);
```

Comment: What do you mean by default format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's because the `toDate` function returns a JS `Date` object. So when you try to console log it, it print a Date Object.

What you need is to use the `format()` function with no parameters. This will format your date to ISO 8601.

```js
const data = moment('Dec, 9th 2019, 05:23 AM', 'MMM Do YYYY, hh:mm A').format();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```